What frequency do long-distance undersea powerlines run at?
I recently saw this photo of the project "NATO-L", or North Atlantic Transmission One-Link. It's an under-sea powerline planned to connect Europe with North America.
Does anyone know what frequency such cables run at? I was thinking it looks like a giant coax cable, and so it must have characteristic impedance and other related parameters. I seem to recall the big over-land powerlines run at 400Hz. I searched google about this cable, but I could not find any information about the frequency.
EDIT: Thank you for the answers about the DC and 400hz. It seems I was incorrect. I do recall seeing something related to powerlines many years ago, and there was definitely something about 400hz, since I've had that number stuck in my head since then. But it seems I misunderstood.


A lot of undersea power cables are high-voltage DC. This one probably isn't, though, as it has three conductors.

Big over-land power cables usually run at whatever the local AC mains frequency is, 50 or 60 Hz. Higher frequency -> higher loss. DC is best, but historically DC to AC inversion was expensive and inefficient.

That photo is a stock image of an undersea cable. That cable is AC, but it's also probably 10 or 20 years old. A cable crossing the north Atlantic would be DC.

”I seem to recall the big over-land powerlines run at 400Hz” They don’t as it would require inverters in both ends to be usable for 50/60 Hz grids (entire world). Also, the cable in your image is a three phase AC submarine cable, suitable for <100 km distance, depending on voltage level.

Where did you find this photo? We would like to see the full article with the text and the photo. You should include the source of the article.

@Uwe That photo came from a post in this group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/ElectronicParts. It was from a user that described what it was and he worked for the company, etc. I have just spent some time trying to find this post again, but I cannot. There are so many in that group. It's possible it was one of those "suggested posts" in my newsfeed from a group I am not a member. I did also search all of FB for phrases I remember from the post, but I still could not find it. I'm sorry if this post is "stock", it was not my intention to mislead anyone.

400 Hz is related only to mobile machines but not to stationary long distance power grids. Due to the centrifugal forces the rotation speed of a powerful, heavy and large generator is limited to less than about 2000 or 4000 r/min. Only small and lightweight generators may rotate much faster with 8000, 12000 or even 24000 r/min. To avoid too many magnetic poles of the generator, 400 Hz is restricted to small generators rotating very fast.

So the photo is not related to the project "NATO-L" and should be deleted.

There are undersea three phase AC cable systems using a single three core cable as well as three single core cables. For lower amounts of power a single three core cable may be used. For larger amounts of power a three core cable would be too heavy to transport.

@Uwe 400 Hz generators use more poles in order to keep the rotational speed down.

@winny yes I know, 24000 r/min with 2 poles or 12000 r/min with 4 poles or 8000 r/min with 6 poles ....

The NATO-L page contains:

NATO-L will connect North America to Western Europe via Eastern Canada and UK & Ireland through a 6GW HVDC set of subsea cables.

I.e. high-voltage DC.

Building a long distance (3300 km) HVDC overhead line above the ground is much easier and cheaper than an undersea cable (3500 km).

@Uwe not to mention easier to maintain. But how to get transatlantic with an overhead cable?

It's DC.
Any AC cable would have significant losses from skin effect.
Since the power grids at each end won't be synchronized, inverters will be required anyway - it's more straightforward  to use DC for the link.

The loss of long AC cables is not caused by only the skin effect. The major problem is the high capacitance of underground or underwater cables causing additional current to charge and discharge the cable capacitance. For very long cables its entire current carrying capability would be needed  by the charging current alone. There is no current left to transport power to the other end of the cable. The capacitance of overhead power lines is much smaller. Of cause the skin effect is valid for both overhead power lines in the air and cables below the surface of the soil or the water.

400 Hz is used within aircrafts and spacecrafts to save weight. The weight of a transformer is much smaller when designed for 400 Hz instead of 50 or 60 Hz. The transmission loss of a (long) cable used with 400 Hz is much higher than used with 50 or 60 Hz.
But for very long distance underwater cables it does not make sense to use 400 Hz instead of 50 Hz. The optimal frequency for such a cable is as low as possible, therefore there are a lot of those cables designed for HVDC (high voltage direct current with "0 Hz").
To exchange power between Europe and North America AC current is not useful anyway because the grids frequencies are different and not synchronized. Conversion from AC to DC and back to AC of another frequency could not be avoided.

Overhead power lines run at 50 Hz in Europe and 60 Hz in the USA. 400 Hz has too much loss and is restricted to planes and ships.

There are single phase overhead power lines run at only 16.7 Hz in Europe used to power the electrified rail networks. If you see pylons with 2 or 4 conductors it is 16,7 Hz. Pylons with 3, 6 or 9 conductors are used for 50 Hz. But Japan has two separate power grids with 50 and 60 Hz. Transfer of power between both grids is possible only using conversion to DC.

16 2/3 Hz, to be precise

@MrGerber To be ultra precise, it once was 16 2/3 Hz but it was changed to 16.7 Hz in October 16th 1995 Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_electrification - Low-frequency alternating current.

I stand corrected! Thanks, @Uwe

400 Hz is used for AC power distribution in US military aircraft and ships.  For example, see MIL-STD-704.

Not only military aircraft but also civil aircraft. Also manned spacecrafts like Apollo and Space Shuttle.
